# error when run an Android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I clone a android project from github, when i run it on my phone, the android monitor says

```
10-20 10:47:06.280 6789-6789/com.example.castoryan.orb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.castoryan.orb, PID: 6789
                                                                         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.2.1_29f2fe0e989481fa50280a028f5e882e46f71793-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.2.1_7117fbe4c4e713f034cb1d8c57d472030a47c772-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.2.1_a2ab3f53bcae00d27ab9cfee6bcea6d0e86508d6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.2.1_1fa6e3f5d64af6cd0cc82e1ace4c4909c52d1921-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.2.1_f4c2af62f943a2f434d4772015f0efc5b2579810-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.castoryan.orb/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.2.1_f3bfe73a3edbcdf71557b98c7782ea66834668ed-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmono.so"
                                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:378)
                                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:998)
                                                                             at com.example.castoryan.orb.MyNDK.<clinit>(MyNDK.java:19)
                                                                             at com.example.castoryan.orb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```